# Incoming Call --> Launch URL

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a simple Requirement:

Incoming Call in Teams --> Popup shows up
External URL can be launched over Button-Click or similar (Incoming Phone-Number can be placed in URL)
Already posted this question on techcommunity.microsoft.com but no answer yet.

Is this Requirement possible to implement? Other Phone-Platforms offer this feature out of the box.

Thank you all,

daprodigy23

Answer (score 0):

With the any official Teams SDK(s) available from Microsoft, no there is not.

The only way to do this is with dodgy methods that may break at any time.
The problems you will face are:

- Teams client is a Electron application that just points to a web page.  So to things like Spy++ it's just a window and the rest is a black box.
- No offical API way to control the teams client

What you could attempt is:

- Spy++ type application to detect when the ringing window is displayed (you can't get the "phone number" from it though as it's a black box).  You may be able to get the ringing person via the window title if you are lucky?
- Windows automation API to detect / pull information from the ringing window.  Can be done, but enabling the automation API against a Electron application slows it down noticeably.
- Use chrome driver to automate the teams client.  This should work but may require a lot of experimenting to get it correct.  The downside of the chrome driver is that you would have to start the teams client in a special way for it to work, i.e. stop the current running teams client and then run the teams client via the chrome driver.
- Use chrome driver to inject javascript into the web site.  This would require a lot of time reverse engineering of web site java script code.  Would give you the best control / information but may be prone to breaking a lot whenever the web site changes (at any time)...  You also have the same problems as above with the running under the chrome driver.